Why doesn't "Save and copy changes to all public communities" save the location field?
How do I change the location listed on my profile on every Stack Exchange site?
If I edit the location on one profile and click "Save and copy changes to all public communities", it only saves for the current site, i.e. the change isn't applied to all of my Stack Exchange profiles.

I can replicate the bug - I changed my location from singapore, singapore to singapore on meta and it didn't propagate to super user.

It would be nice to get a response from SE on this since the bug has existed since 2018 and has to do with sensitive information.

@CaptainMan this isn't even in review yet - it's not on SE radar even in the remote case they had a spare developer to take a look.

@ShadowWizard wild considering this could be GDPR related.

@CaptainMan how exactly? If you can explain please write answer to the original bug report, it might make SE respond faster.

@ShadowWizard A user's location is personal information

@CaptainMan OK, and? We can still remove the location, and someone with 100+ accounts can probably submit contact form asking to delete the location from all accounts if it becomes an issue and the bug prevents them from doing it.

@ShadowWizard Why the sarcasm?
